# Ads for European Economic Area (EEA) using Tag For Under Age of Consent (TFUA)

Tags: android, ios, admob

When implementing AdMob into my mobile app I get an error when attempting to display the consent form after I set Tag For Under Age Of Consent (as all my users are expected to be children).

First I set Tag For Under Age Of Consent using:

```
ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true);
```

Then attempting to show the consent form and I get an error. I found additional information about this at: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#users_under_the_age_of_consent

However, I am a bit confused as to what is needed. Do I need to display a custom consent form if I have TFUA set or does setting TFUA no longer require a consent form at all?

Answer (score 1):

As described on the developer [document](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#users_under_the_age_of_consent) when you set Tag for Users under the age of consent

> Once the TFUA setting is enabled, the Google-rendered consent form
>   will fail to load. All ad requests that include TFUA will be made
>   ineligible for personalized advertising and remarketing. TFUA disables
>   requests to third-party ad technology providers, such as ad
>   measurement pixels and third-party ad servers.

For your query, you do not require a consent form.

As per my understanding, even if you try showing personalized ads, it will still display non-personalized ads. In one of the app which I developed for kids, I m getting error as it is failing to display the form due to this tag, I myself calling the setting to show Non - Personalized ads.

Comment: Hi, how will this tag influence ad mediation? Is adding the tag enough to disable personalised ads and data collection by other ad networks added in an Admob mediation group?